# Qt5 Qregexp : why my pattern can't work?

Tags: regex, qt5, qregexp

I get this problem When I open a text file, I can't get any matched string. Then I test this pattern: .* but I can either get nothing. I'm sure the text file can be read, and the pattern can be accepted in grep. Thank you.

```
QList<Nmap_result> ans;
QFile file(path);
if(!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly|QFile::Text))
{
    exit(1);
}

QString text = file.readAll();
QRegExp reg(QRegExp::escape(".*"));

reg.indexIn(text);
qDebug()<<reg.capturedTexts().join("|")<<endl<<reg.captureCount()<<endl;
```

Sorry, I should not use escape. But when I change it like this:

```
QString text = file.readAll();
qDebug()<<text<<endl;
QRegExp reg("[0-9]");

//reg.indexIn(text);          //first bind expr test
reg.exactMatch(text);       //second bind expr test
qDebug()<<reg.capturedTexts().join("|!!!!!|")<<endl<<reg.captureCount()<<endl;
```

I use

```
reg.indexIn(text);
```

to bind this string to regexp, it return a number,but when I use the next expr

```
reg.exeacMatch(text);
```

I get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you call `QRegExp::escape` method ?

Try this instead:

```
 QRegExp reg(".*");
```

Calling `QRegExp::escape`, your regular expression becomes similar to this string: `"\\.\\*"`. This string indicates that you want to match a dot immediatly followed by a star. This is not the intented use here: match zero or more characters (`.*`).